# Procedure names and quotation marks

Tags: sql

I'm currently learning about SQL procedures, and I've encountered this problem:
I've seen that when creating a new procedure, some declare its name with and without quotation marks. For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_tra (IN conductor varchar(3))

CREATE PROCEDURE `my_proc_LOOP` (IN num INT)
```

Is it because the second one has LOOP in its name?

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

No.  The *entire* name has to conflict with a reserved word -- and even in that case, the better solution is to change the name of the identifier rather than escape it.

The two are essentially equivalent.  In databases that support backticks, the backticks are used to escape irregular names -- say those that conflict with keywords or those that have spaces.  Escaping identifiers can also lead to problems with the case of the letters.  By default, upper case and lower case are usually the same for identifiers that are not escaped.

Because you should only use regular names, backticks really are not necessary.  I would just drop them.